Inheritance of singleton class for multiple modules not working
Im trying to create multiple children classes that share the same singleton parent class. Meanwhile, the singleton parent class is being initialised for each child, missing the singleton propose. This is a single package where each child is in each module which are in the end initialised in the init.
I believe the issue is due the the fact the parent class being imported in each child module.
Bellow is the singleton class.
#server.py
class DeviceI_O:


    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(DeviceI_O, cls).__new__(cls)
            cls._instance.__initialized = False
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self):
        if self.__initialized:
            return
        self.__initialized = True
        print('init once')

The init of the package:

from .trap_controller import TrapControler
from .flowcell_stage import FlowCell
from .camera_controller import CameraController
from .calibration import Calibration
from .server import DeviceI_O


pm = TrapControler('pm')
aod = TrapControler('aod')
flowcell = FlowCell()
calibrate = Calibration() 
cameraController = CameraController()

And now each child is the following:
# example flowcell
from .server import DeviceI_O

class FlowCell(DeviceI_O):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.DAQ=40 #Hz

#example trapcontrol

from .server import DeviceI_O


class TrapControler(DeviceI_O):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self._name = name



When i initialise the package i got ('init once') four times.
How can i do this such way i only get the server initialised once as a singleton.

This doesn't make sense. I think you've misunderstood how inheritance works. You might want to use composition instead, but we don't have enough context to know how best to approach your underlying task.

what do you mean by composition? i want for all the child classes to share the same two sockets that are created in the device_IO

__init__ initializes instances, not the parent class. Further, self.__initialized always creates a new instance attribute; it never modifies an existing class attribute.

You have the concepts of inheritance and reference mixed up.
Defining your child as a inherited class as you did, gets you to have every children with the same behaviors as your parent class.
What you want is to create an instance (i.e. a real version of a class) that is common to every children you have.
So what you have done is (in its structure) equivalent to :
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, name): #name is dummy variable
        print("init once")
        self.name = name

    def a_method(self):
        #Do something
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.super(name)
        #At that point self.name is equal to name
        #And the Child have also "a_method" from Parent

c1 = Child('Alice')
c2 = Child('Bob')
c3 = Child('Charlie')

And the output will be :
init once
init once
init once

What you want, is for every child, pass the parent as an argument:
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("init once")
        self.name = name

    def a_method(self):
        #Do something
        pass

class Child: #Note that the Child inherits from nothing
    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent

parent = Parent("John")
c1 = Child("Alice", parent)
c2 = Child("Bob", parent)

The ouput would be :
init once

And if you actually need to call a method from parent at one point in your child definitions, you can write:
#In class Child:
def child_method(self)
    self.parent.a_method()

Now you instantiate only once a parent and create every child you want from this instance.
Note : I kept using your "Child/Parent" vocabulary even though they are abusive in the case of just passing a reference of the parent to the child, but correspondences are kept intact

In the device_IO i create 2 sockets. i dont want to create these two sockets for each child. i want for it to be shared for all childs. i had in the beginning the same way that you mentioned, as passing the class as an argument. It works but i though it looked poorly written, so i looked into singleton thinking it would be a good oportunity to learn since i never used them.

The left side of
cls._instance = super(DeviceI_O, cls).__new__(cls)

treats cls as the child-class, not the parent, so the _instance attribute now exists for the parent (None) and separately for the child. So each child creates its own instance. You can fix it by replacing it by DeviceI_O._instance = super(DeviceI_O, cls).__new__(cls).
Other than that, I don't understand, why you'd want that design. Your Singleton is of the type of the child that is initialized first and there's no point in having different identifiers for it. You call TrapController twice with different parameters, which means the first call is pointless, as the second call overwrites its state.

I wanted to learn how to use singletons but i guess it was a bad time. The device_IO creates 2 sockets that i want for it to be shared for all the child classes. I thought with a singleton, the same parent class would be accessed by each child class

You should probably read https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202204/singleton_is_a_bad_idea.html.

Your problem lies in the first 4 lines of code there:
class DeviceI_O:

    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            ...

If DeviceI_O itself never gets instantiated, this even might work, creating one instance of each child class.
The problem is that when DeviceI_O itself is instantiated, the _instance attribute it refers to is set to something other than None. And then when a subclass is instantiated, the condition if cls._instance is None:  will fail: when trying to lookup the ._instance attribute, and not finding it on the subclass, Python will pick the attribute from the superclass - which is set to the singleton instance of DeviceI_O itself.
This is easily fixable by using a proper registry in the superclass, with a dictionary containing all singletons, and checking for the proper class instance when creating a new one. Also, it is a nice place to use the __ prefix for an attribute, which will make Python mangle the attribute name at compile time, making it hard for subclasses to mess with this registry by accident:
class DeviceI_O:

    _registry = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # The special name `__class__` will always refer to _this_ class
        # (where the code containing `__class__` is defined)
        if __class__.__registry.get(cls) is None:
            instance = super().__new__(cls)
            instance.__initialized = False
            __class__.__registry[cls] = instance
        return __class__._registry[cls]

